# Hide a view in Titanium so that it does not take physical space

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

In titanium it is possible to hide a view like so:

```
$.foo.hide()
```

or

```
$.foo.visible = false
```

However, in both cases the object still seems to take physical space. It is just invisible. In other words it is similar to the CSS property `visibility: hidden`.

I want it so that it disappears and take no physical space in terms of width or height, so it's similar to the CSS property `display: none`

How can I do this?

The best hacky solution I have is the following:

```
$.foo.width = 0;
$.foo.height = 0;
$.foo.left = 0;
$.foo.right = 0;
```

But that means when I want to make it visible again, I have to set all those properties back to their original values which is a pain and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't afraid of doing some hard coding ;)

Coming to your query, yes, this is true that hiding a view just hide it from UI, but physical-space is still there.

To do what you want, you will need to either remove view on hide & create it on show, or you can use **absolute layout** in some tricky way.

Other way could be to animate this view using transform property like this:

```
// on hide
$.foo.animate({
   duration : 100,
   transform : Ti.UI.create2DMatrix({scale:0})
}, function () {
   $.foo.visible = false;
});


// on show
$.foo.visible = true;    // we need to make it visible again before resetting its UI state since we hid it after completion of animation in above code
$.foo.animate({
    duration : 100,
    transform : Ti.UI.create2DMatrix()  // passing empty matrix will reset the initial state of this view
});
```

**OR**

this could also work but never tried this:

```
// on hide
$.foo.transform = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix({scale:0});
$.foo.visible = false;

// on show
$.foo.visible = true;
$.foo.transform = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
```

Comment: The 2D matrix approach did not seem to work. It managed to make the view disappear, but unfortunately it still takes physical space.

Comment: Try with some minor value of scale like 0.05, if it also doesn't work, then your only option is to decrease the height/width or remove/add view